# Merging vectors in R keeping only a specific value

Tags: r, vector, merge, logical-operators

I would like to merge two vectors while keeping the resultant vector of the same dimension but overwriting values if the meet a specific criteria.

In this case, I have two vectors of T and F values. Let's say

```
A <- c(T F T F)
B <- c(T T F F)
```

I would like to merge them and obtain a vector that retains TRUE if it appears in either vector, such that

```
C <- c(T T T F)
```

It would be nice to get code that could handle any value (not just TRUE), but not necessary.

Spent about two hours trying to figure this out without success so I really appreciate the community's input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier than that, just `A | B`.

Comment: And its counterpart `A&B`. Thanks.

Comment: Very nice. Looks like mastering logical operators would be quite useful. I think I know what I'll start doing this weekend.

Answer (score 1):

What about using boolean operations ? To retain `TRUE` values, you may want to do

```
> !!(A+B)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Or to retain `FALSE` values,

```
> !!(A*B)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

However, this may not be what you exactly want since this solution cannot deal with types that are not boolean.

---

Note that MattTyers's answer is even simpler than mine, since it does boolean operations whitout turning binary numbers into decimal ones.

Comment: Thanks. It works, but I am not sure why. I tried (A+B) just to see what happens and saw that it does pretty much the same thing but outputs 0s and 1s. With one NOT statement (!) it first turned all the 0s and 1s into booleans, but then negated them. And with the !!(A+B) that you suggested, I got what I was looking for. Why were the "!" necessary to produce booleans? Hope I'm not taking up too much of your time. Just curious. Thanks!

Comment: @trijamms. The question of the "why", or even more "how", is not that easy to answer actually. But since any numbers, 0 excepted, is considered to be `TRUE`, when you negate a number like so `!1` it actually involves boolean operations whose result can only be a boolean. Then doing, e.g. `!!1`, negate `!1` (`FALSE`), which thus returns `TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks Tnerual. That actually makes sense.

Comment: That's pretty clever btw, using the `!` logical operator to coerce a numeric back to logical.

Comment: **coerce**. The word I was searching for.